# Explain the usage of Abstractfunction1 in scala

Tags: scala

Can you guys help me to understand the usage of scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 in scala. Why we need to override the apply method in it .

Comment: "Why we need to override the apply method in it ." Please explain,. "We" don't.

Comment: I dont get your answer.  What's the purpose of that abstractfunction1 ?

Comment: I didn't answer. I commented. I don't understand why you said "Why we need to override the apply method on iit"? It's an abstract class - you have to define anything left undefined/abstract in order to get a instantiable subclass, just like any other abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes in `scala.runtime` are just implementation details used by code generated by the compiler. They shouldn't normally appear in user code.

There is one exception: if you need to call a method taking `scala.Function*` (where `*` is the number of arguments) *from Java*, you should use a (usually anonymous) class extending `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction*`, because the Java compiler doesn't know about Scala traits. But that isn't a "usage of scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 in scala", so not relevant to this question.

You can also extend `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction*` instead of `scala.Function*` in Scala, but this has the same result (with slightly smaller generated code).